# why my less source maps don't work?

Tags: less, source-maps, gulp-less, gulp-sourcemaps

I use the gulp-less compiler with gulp-sourcemaps write the source maps file.

but it don't work in my chrome dev tool, I can't see the content of less. only css file.

it's my gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var path = require('path');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('less', function () {

 return gulp.src('src/less/*.less')
  .pipe(less())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
  .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'));

});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('src/less/*.less', ['less']);
});
```

[image]

Comment: Text is way more easier than trying to read images.

Comment: `sourcemaps.init()` must be called *before* any module that generates sourcemaps.

Comment: ok, that's my problem. I used that gulp-less is very old version.  the new version is working.